# Swift пуш уведомления и notification center

Tags: swift, уведомления, push, observer

День добрый! У меня следующий вопрос:
В моем приложении написан функционал по получению пуш уведомлений, все работает пока приложение в Foreground и Background, проблемы когда приложение закрыто. Я посылаю пуш уведомление с текстом и с параметром.
Когда приложение закрыто - пуш уведомление приходят - при нажатии на пуш - приложение открывается, но не срабатывает функция pushNotificationHandler.
Когда приложение открыто или свернуто - все работает без проблем.

```
AppDelegate
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
{
    let userInfo                    = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    let notification : NSDictionary = userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
    let parameters    : String?      = notification.object(forKey: “parameters”) as? String
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: “notification”) , object: parameters, userInfo: response.notification.request.content.userInfo)

ViewController
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(pushNotificationHandler(_:)),
                                       name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: “notification”),
                                       object: nil)
{

@objc func pushNotificationHandler(_ notification : NSNotification){
    let myObj = notification.object as? String
    print(myObj!)
}
```

Подскажите плиз, что в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если приложение закрыто, то некому вызывать метод селектора.

И еще, из документации на UIApplicationDidFinishLaunching:

> If the notification was posted for a normal app launch, there is no
>   userInfo dictionary.